# jQuery tools and jquery.ui.ufd-0.6

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-tools

I'm developing a web site and I added jquery tools to use its date picker, recenty I wanted to change the way the select elements looked and I found the jquery.ui.ufd plugin. As its names reads it depends on jquery ui but even though I added jquery ui I keep getting this error: jQuery.widget is not a function. My guess is I can't use jquery tools and jquery ui together. I want to know if the is any work around this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without sample code, it's hard to say, but jquery and jqueryui work fine with each other.  For appearance, you might want to consider [Themeroller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/), another feature designed for jqueryui.

Comment: Oh!! it works just fine I just had to load jQuery tools before ufd, thanks for your time

Comment: @user607502 Glad I could help - the customary way of thanking someone on Stack Overflow is to accept, and/or upvote the answers that worked for you.

Comment: Sorry, I'm kind of new to stack overflow

Comment: No problem, thus a polite "nudge" so that you understand how everyone gets along.  The more you ask, answer, and accept, they better your reputation becomes, giving you more creditibilty with whatever you're doing here.